# Name Validation Using Regular Expressions

Tags: javascript, html, regex

I'm using a regular expression in my code, to validate the name and send the form, I just need some help by using it.

The Name should start by a capital letter and could be from 2-3 words, and could be separated by an apostrophe, space or a dash such as :

> Victor Hugo
>
> Jeanne D'arc
>
> Jean-Marc Ayrault

I tried starting it by a capital, using `/^[A-z][a-z]/`
But i don't know how to continue it to validate spaces and dashes and apostrophes.

`/^[A-z][a-z]/`

I don't know how to continue it, thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try the code below:

I'd suggest playing about with https://regexr.com/ for this purpose, it's very handy!

I've added a isValidNameStrict which only accepts a limited number of characters in the name.

Modify the [a-z'] group as you see fit to add extra characters.

```js
function isValidNameStrict(name) {
    let regEx = /^([A-Z][a-z']*[\-\s]?){2,}$/;
    return regEx.test(name);
}

function isValidName(name) {
    let regEx = /^(?:[A-Z][^\s]*\s?){2}$/;
    return regEx.test(name);
}

function testName(name) {
    console.log(`'${name}' is ${isValidNameStrict(name) ? "valid": "not valid"}`);
}

testName("Victor Hugo");
testName("Jeanne D'arc");
testName("Jean-Marc Ayrault");
testName("The Rock");
testName("Victor hugo");
testName("");
testName("Ozymandias");
```

Comment: It worked perfectly, please can you explain to understand what happened?

Comment: @RaffyEid: This would match `Victor123 Hu@@@##go` too claiming it as valid. Do you really want to allow any junk in name?

Comment: We're being more permissive than needs be perhaps.. easy to change however. You'd need to quantify what is a valid character in a name. I'm certain there will be more than - and ' though :)

Comment: @PushpeshKumarRajwanshi Thank you for saying sir, I didn't expect it, no I don't want it.
The problem is I didn't understand regex well, I'm just trying to understand what's happening

Answer (score 2):

You can use this regex,

```
\b[A-Z][a-z]*(?:'[a-z]+)?(?:[ -][A-Z][a-z]*(?:'[a-z]+)?)*\b
```

**Explanation:**

- `\b[A-Z][a-z]*` - Starts matching a word boundary and uppercase letter followed by zero or more lowercase letters
- `(?:'[a-z]+)?` - Optionally followed by `'` and some lowercase letters. If you want to repeat this more than once, change `?` to `*` like if you really want to support names like `D'arcd'arc` which I doubt if you wanted which is why I kept it with `?`
- `(?:[ -]` - Starts another non-grouping pattern and starts matching either with a space or hyphen
- `[A-Z][a-z]*(?:'[a-z]+)?)*` - Further matches the same structure as in start of regex and zero or more times.
- `\b` - Stops after seeing a word boundary

**[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/EZ5GoD/1/)**